# AlphaAnimation Not Working in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am display a layout with fade animation by manipulating its alpha levels using `AlphaAnimation`.

The current solution works fine on two of my devices which use Gingerbread and one which uses Froyo. However, it does not work on Ice Cream Sandwich?!

Here is my xml layout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/photoOptionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:background="@color/gpsBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/displayShareBtn"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless.Small"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/share"
            android:contentDescription="Share the picture"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/displayDiscardBtn"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless.Small"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/contentdiscard"
            android:contentDescription="Discard Picture"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my onCreate method to set the alpha to 0 on loadup as when done in xml it doesn't work...

```
    AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.0F, 0.0F);
    alpha.setDuration(0); // Make animation instant
    alpha.setFillAfter(true); // Tell it to persist after the animation ends
    // And then on your layout
    this._photoOptionsBar.startAnimation(alpha);
```

And then when I want to show it I call the following.

```
public void showOptions() {
        AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.0F, 1.0F);
        alpha.setDuration(PhotoDisplayFragment.FADE_DURATION); // Make animation instant
        alpha.setFillAfter(true);
        this._photoOptionsBar.startAnimation(alpha);
        this._optionsShowing = true;
}
```

When I load it up in IceCream sandwich the LinearLayout is there because you can click the buttons and it executes their function, and the functions to show are being called but I just can't see it!

Any help would be great

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with `android:alpha=0` in the Linear Layout. To make things work you have to set visibility property to invisible in layout xml. And before starting alpha animation call `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

Comment: You were correct with where the problem was, however setting it to 1 in the xml file made the rest work fine.

Comment: Yea couldn't because of timer.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem.

It seems like there are two separate alpha properties. `AlphaAnimation` changes one, and `android:alpha` changes the other. Both properties are used on ICS, but `android:alpha` is ignored pre-ICS.

So if you set `android:alpha="0"` and use `AlphaAnimation` to do the animation, pre-ICS it will work fine, since `android:alpha` is ignored. On ICS the view will always be invisible because `AlphaAnimation` doesn't change `android:alpha` from 0. Therefore the solution is simply to remove the `android:alpha="0"` line.

I'm not 100% sure about this, but that's how it seems to behave.

I also think the two alphas work in a slightly different way. Certainly if you change the alpha of an `ImageView` with a semi-transparent image it looks much worse with `AlphaAnimation` than `android:alpha`. But there's not much you can do about that.